# Send S3 document to Textract using Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-textract

I'm trying to use Go to send objects in a S3 bucket to Textract and collect the response.

I'm using the aws go sdk package and able to connect to my S3 bucket and list all the objects contained within. So far so good. I now need to be able to send one of those objects (a .pdf file) to Textract and collect the response(s).

The AWS Go SDK content for interacting with Textract seem to be quite extensive but I cannot find a good example for how to do this.

I would be very grateful for a sample or advice on how to do this.

Comment: Did you ever find a working example?

Amazon is amazing in that they generate gigabytes of documentation and none of it is actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

To start a job, you invoke [`StartDocumentTextDetection`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/textract/#Textract.StartDocumentTextDetection), using a [`DocumentLocation`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/textract/#DocumentLocation) to specify the file, and you specify a SNS topic where Textract will publish a notification when it has finished to process your job.

You have now two possibilities:

- Subscribe to the SNS topic, and when you receive a message retrieve the result
- Create a lambda function triggered by the SNS topic, which retrieves the result.

The second option is IMO better 'cause it use less computation time (doesn't run until the job hasn't finished).

To retrieve the job, you use [`GetDocumentTextDetection`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/textract/#Textract.GetDocumentTextDetection)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else reaches this site searching for an answer:

I understood the documentation as if I could just call the StartDocumentAnalysis function through the textract SDK but in fact what was missing is the fact that you need to create a new Session first and do the calls based on the session:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/textract/#New